# Adobe Flash Builder does not refresh a value object

Tags: java, apache-flex, blazeds

I'm currently facing a problem with Adobe Flash Builder, I work on a project with a Java core and services to communicate with a Flex client. (BlazeDS channel)

I decided to remove an array list in an object because it was no longer useful, so I commented the following lines in my object value to remove the `ArrayList` named "unitFactors"

```
public class UnitValue extends PhysicalQuantityObjectValue{

    String symbol;
    String name;
    String description;
    String physicalQuantityName;
    //UnitFactorValue[] unitFactors;
    UnitConstraintValue unitConstraint;

    public UnitValue(AdnUnit unit) {
        super(unit.getId());

        //Constructor code ...
    }

    public UnitValue() {}

    public String getSymbol() {
        return symbol;
    }

    public void setSymbol(String symbol) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getPhysicalQuantityName() {
        return physicalQuantityName;
    }

    public UnitValue(String symbol, String name, String description,
            String physicalQuantityName,
            UnitConstraintValue unitConstraint) {
        super();
        this.symbol = symbol;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.physicalQuantityName = physicalQuantityName;
        //this.unitFactors = unitFactors;
        this.unitConstraint = unitConstraint;
    }

    public void setPhysicalQuantityName(String physicalQuantityName) {
        this.physicalQuantityName = physicalQuantityName;
    }

    //public UnitFactorValue[] getUnitFactors() {
        //return unitFactors;
    //}

    //public void setUnitFactors(UnitFactorValue[] unitFactors) {
        //this.unitFactors = unitFactors;
    //}

    public UnitConstraintValue getUnitConstraint() {
        return unitConstraint;
    }

    public void setUnitConstraint(UnitConstraintValue unitConstraint) {
        this.unitConstraint = unitConstraint;
    }
```

Well, no problem with the Java part. I tested it with SoapUI, everything's fine.

But when I switch on my Flex client code to refresh the valueObjects, it appears impossible to refresh UnitValue, unitFactors is still there, and it's obviously impossible to make my application work without errors on that specific point ... Can't find `getUnitFactors()`.

Is someone facing the same problem with AdobeFlashBuilder?

Comment: How do you access `UnitValue` in Flex? How is your ActionScript class (RemoteClass) looking?

Comment: If ActionScript class and Remote Java class are mapped correctly  and you have compiled both then it might be an issue with the browser cache. Please clear your browser cache completely and try again.

Comment: Well, I cleaned the browser cache and it know works perfectly, thanks a lot !

Comment: Good to hear, it worked!